# Организация классов парсера в MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Не до конца понимаю, что должно лежать в `Model`, а что во `ViewModel`.

К примеру, задача парсить сообщения пользователей.
Есть такой класс:

```
class Post
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int LikeCount { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно ли класть Get-запрос, забирающий страницу с сообщением, и регулярки, которые будут выдирать нужную информацию в этот же класс или это все должно находится в PostVM?

Comment: Как я понимаю в Model то, что у вас.  В VM получение списка постов, разбор и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

Сообщения пользователя — это то, с чем работает ваша программа, типичная модель. Разбор их должен быть в модели. Как именно вы получаете это самое сообщение и как вытягиваете из него информацию, для VM не интересно.

VM должна получать лишь готовую к использованию информацию из модели, преобразовывать её удобным для себя образом, и выставлять в UI.

---

Ваш класс `Post` выглядит как DTO-объект. Для VM я бы убрал сеттеры из доступности: не дело VM менять сообщения, это дело модели.

Comment: Понял, спасибо! 
Еще интересен один момент: изначально у меня получается список ссылок на посты (детальная информация не доступна, если не открыть пост отдельно), а затем уже по каждой из ссылок получается пост и из него парсится нужная информация.
Я правильно понимаю, что при таком подходе логика получения списка ссылок на посты должна быть реализована отдельной модели?

Comment: @maxwell: Да, это ещё один модельный класс. Именно так.

Comment: Он выглядит как anemic model, что не то же самое что DTO

Comment: @vitidev: Я бы тоже не предлагал DTO, парсер — довольно толстая модель.

Answer (score 1):

Model:

```
public class PostModel
{
  public string Author {get; set;}
  ....
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
  // Коллекция постов
  public ICollection<Post> Posts {get;}

public void GetPosts()
{
 Posts = ....
...
}

public void CreatePost(Post post)
{
  ....
}

public void UpdatePost(Post post)
{
  ....
}

public void DeletePost(Post post)
{
  ....
}
}
```